# Python assignment operator: Right operand is also modified when Left operand is modified

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am doing this simple thing, but I don't expect the right operand (`apples`) to be modified when I modify the left operand(`bananas`).

```
>> apples = [1,2,3,4,5]
>> bananas = apples
>> bananas.remove(3)
>> bananas 
   [1,2,4,5]
>> apples 
   [1,2,4,5]
```

`apples` should be `[1,2,3,4,5]` instead of `[1,2,4,5]`.

Please comment on this.

Regards.

Comment: https://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way avoid it use:

```
bananas = []+apples
```

Comment: To copy a list, usually you use `bananas = apples[:]`.

Comment: To copy a list that might have embedded references use `bananas = copy.deepcopy(apples)`